# WPF - Bind a List<T> as the contents of a WrapPanel

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, binding

Is is possible to make the contents(children) of a WrapPanel to be bound to a dependency property?

What I am thinking is having a dependency property that is of type List and then define a template for MyClass.

Then have the WrapPanel display them.

I know this is much easier done with a list box, but due to other constraints, I need to try with a WrapPanel before going to a list box.

I am using MVVM.  I would prefer doing this in that pattern.  If I were to break out of MVVM I could just use an event or name it and fill it at load time.  I am hoping there is a binding way that is cleaner.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

`ItemsControl` is your friend:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding YourChildItems}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Not what I was looking for.  But I will take it.  (I needed a control with `Childern` that could be bound to.  I modified my scenario to fit this though.

Comment: The items of the `ItemsControl` become the children of the `ItemsControl`'s panel.